# Deployment hell, Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have to deploy our web project on several (possible 10) servers , We've developed Nant script that doing the Job , but We've face with problem , that Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll that is one of the dependencies doesn't deployed what ever we do.

Could anyone please explain how can add reference to this dll , and mark it copy local or something ? I'll try to explain what's hapening , when I am adding reference to this dll to our proj , the reference added to web.config like :

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly .... blah blah />
</assemblies>
```

This means that assembly should be in GAC , right ? I can see it well if I am clicking on Property Pages in visual studio , and going to refereces tab , I can see that this Dll is in Gac.

Ok , the following command

```
gacutil.exe -l Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure returns with no Result !
```

So where is this assembly stored ? How the magic is done by Microsoft ???

How can I remove it from GAC ???

Anyone ?

PS. One of the possible resolutions that I've found on web. Is to run Package Manager and install it from there again ... but for me it's not a options , we aren't connected to internet for security reasons.

Comment: I doubt if your conclusion is correct about the location of the assembly how it is declared in the web.config.

Comment: References go in the *.csproj file. (Hit the contextmenu on your project, choose unload, then choos edit). Find the References element. Everything without a Hintpath is not in the GAC..

Comment: I don't know , but this is fact... it is not exists in Gac (at least I can't see it neither in C:/Windows/Assembly or via gacutil.exe -l. But it is for sure added from Gac !

Comment: For my fresh MVC project `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll` comes from its NuGET package as part of the solution. That still leaves your original question: why won't that dll deploy...

Comment: I've forgot to mention that this is Wesite project and not Web Application...

Comment: What version of VS and MVC?

Comment: It's ASP.NET 4 , vs 2012. But I have installation of asp.net MVC , and maybe because of this I have Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll in GAC.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35730/discussion-between-rene-and-stringbuilder)

Answer (score 0):

If you've developed against MVC assuming its installed in the GAC why don't you just install it on the target server via http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3

The copy local solution is great if you've got a proj file to work with but you don't as you opted for a website project which is all sln and web.config.

You could add a reference via your websites property page (from your nuget package)
You sound like you already have nuget package but if not you just right click on the bin folder and manage packages - **Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure** - install
If you add this package reference to your bin folder you'll see a new file:
bin\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll.refresh

This just contains a link to actual dll in the package - `..\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll`

The dll will get copied over to the bin folder at build time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use webmatrix / web platform installer to install the DLL on each of the servers.